# How to compare TFS2013 on-premise and Visual Studio Online?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'm advising my company to upgrade our on-premise TFS 2008 to a newer version. As i see it, there are two options available to us: TFS 2013 (on-premise), or Visual Studio Online.

We are a small developer shop inside a larger (non-it) business, and would like to work internally and externally with a source control system. We have chosen to adopt the Microsoft stack, so other alternatives are not desired for us.

How do i compare the on-premise TFS2013 offering to Visual Studio Online? I'm concerned about costs, scaleabillty (up- and down), working with multiple parties, continuous integration builds, continuous deployment, unit- and integration tests. We develop mainly on BizTalk, WCF and some custom C# applications.

**Does anyone have advise or experience comparing these two offerings?**

Comment: Do you already have MSDN licenses?

Comment: Yep, for about ~15 developers.

Comment: With regards to features you can compare here: http://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/news/release-archive-vso

Comment: This is too broad for SO really. But, IMO, if the features in VSOnline are enough for you, why would you want to buy "tin" and manage it when you can let MS do it for you?

Comment: @DaveShaw can i rephrase the question to get a better answer? or can i ask this question better elsewhere?

Comment: Try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn519923.aspx

Answer (score 5):

The main differences:

1) VSO is always up to date.

2) VSO doesn't have a cube to pull reports from

3) You can't customize your process template in VSO

Comment: All good points. I'd also add that if you want more control over the up time of TFS, then a local install is important. For the most part, VSO has been available. However, there have been multiple occasions over the past year where it has gone down (we've been using VSO for just over a year now) and been unavailable for several hours at a time. However, since we have also opted to use Git-based repositories, the downtime has been less of an impact as it would have been if we were still using Team Foundation Version Control. The stability has been improving but is far from perfect.

Comment: True, in a way. However a major downtime event for VSO is measured in hours, whereas a major downtime event for a small to medium size organization can often be measured in days. The comparison is highly dependent on your own internal stability and disaster recovery ability. Also, with local workspaces in TFVC, the downtime is almost as seamless as Git, with the biggest difference being the inability to commit locally.

Comment: I completely agree. If your organization has the resources, then you likely have more control over your uptime with a local instance of TFS. Otherwise, you might be better off with VSO. In our case, we currently run TFS on premises (have been since 2005) but are actively moving all projects into VSO and will do away with our TFS instance in the relatively near future :-)

Answer (score 2):

In my limited usage of VSOnline, i found that it does almost evrything a TFS 2013 does.
Code repository- check ,  Build- check   ,  Build drop folder - check   ,  Ms build + deploy- check  ,  agile managemnt - check,  bug managemnt - check

what else would a small dev team what ?

go through this link http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/hosted-build-controller-vs#software .